# Iterate items json array

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

I would like to ask for help.
I have json array.
How can I make iterating array after split and create csv output

My input is...

```
[
    {
        "body": [
            {
                "title": "topinfo",
                "longText": "item1|details item 1|details sdfdfdfd ||details gbgfgghmhjmh||details 5348786"
            },
            {
                "title": "topinfo",
                "longText": "item2|details item 2|details sdfdfdfd ||details gbgfgghmhjmh||details 9784561"
            }
            ]
    }
]
```

My actually call for jq ...

```
jq '.[] | [.body[] | {longText,title} ] | to_entries | map( (.value.level = "\(1+.key)" ) | .value) | .[] | [.title,.level,(.longText|split("|"))] '
```

Actually result

```
[
  "topinfo",
  "1",
  [
    "item1",
    "details item 1",
    "details sdfdfdfd",
    "details gbgfgghmhjmh",
    "details 5348786"
  ]
]
[
  "topinfo",
  "2",
  [
    "item2",
    "details item 2",
    "details sdfdfdfd",
    "details gbgfgghmhjmh",
    "details 9784561"
  ]
]
```

And I would like to expect this csv...

> ```
> topinfo;1;1;item1
> topinfo;1;2;details item 1
> topinfo;1;3;details sdfdfdfd
> topinfo;1;4;details gbgfgghmhjmh
> topinfo;1;5;details 5348786
>
> topinfo;2;1;item2
> topinfo;2;2;details item 2
> topinfo;2;3;details sdfdfdfd
> topinfo;2;4;details gbgfgghmhjmh
> topinfo;2;5;details 9784561
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Nesting iterations and variable bindings:

```bash
.[].body                                                   # top-level iteration
| to_entries[] as {key: $i, value: {$title, $longText}}    # collect values
| $longText / "|"                                          # split at "|"
| map(select(. != ""))                                     # remove empty items(?)
| (                                                        # open grouping context
    to_entries[] as {key: $j, $value}                      # collect values
    | [$title, $i+1, $j+1, $value]                         # prepare output line
    | join(";")                                            # join to string
  ), ""                                                    # add empty line
```

```
topinfo;1;1;item1
topinfo;1;2;details item 1
topinfo;1;3;details sdfdfdfd 
topinfo;1;4;details gbgfgghmhjmh
topinfo;1;5;details 5348786

topinfo;2;1;item2
topinfo;2;2;details item 2
topinfo;2;3;details sdfdfdfd 
topinfo;2;4;details gbgfgghmhjmh
topinfo;2;5;details 9784561
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/76cw8olnozZ)

To properly escape for a CSV output, use `@csv` instead of `join(";")`. Note that this would "join" by comma instead of semicolon, and quote the items if necessary:

```
"topinfo",1,1,"item1"
"topinfo",1,2,"details item 1"
"topinfo",1,3,"details sdfdfdfd "
"topinfo",1,4,"details gbgfgghmhjmh"
"topinfo",1,5,"details 5348786"

"topinfo",2,1,"item2"
"topinfo",2,2,"details item 2"
"topinfo",2,3,"details sdfdfdfd "
"topinfo",2,4,"details gbgfgghmhjmh"
"topinfo",2,5,"details 9784561"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/j4KA_mTGGcC)

Comment: Solution is again  perfect. Guys, you are not from this world ;-)